# How to handle onPause and onResume within adapter?

Tags: android, adapter, android-recyclerview, onpause

How to do changes to recycler view's item onPause and onResume ?

Comment: Can you share your code here??

Comment: It's simply a dialog in the recyclerview with play pause button . The code is too big to share and everything's so connected that i couldn't summarize and you won't be able get much . I'm pretty sure both of my questions are generic and don't require to look into the code

Comment: can you try your function onResume Method.

Comment: i don't understand what you are trying to say ?

Comment: share some code please

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with the help of `interface`

### Define interface

```
 interface OnActivityStateChanged{
    fun onResumed()
    fun onPaused()
}
```

### In your adapter, Define a function to register the interface

```
 fun registerActivityState()  = object : OnActivityStateChanged{
    override fun onResumed() {
        Log.d("SimpleTextListAdapter", "onResumed: ")
    }

    override fun onPaused() {

        Log.d("SimpleTextListAdapter", "onPaused: ")
    }

}
```

### Create and inititalize interface in activity

```
var onActivityStateChanged:OnActivityStateChanged? = null
...

// after adapter intitialization, intialize your interface
onActivityStateChanged  = adapter.registerActivityState()
```

### Finally, in your activity cycle methods

```
override fun onPause() {
    onActivityStateChanged?.onPaused()
    super.onPause()
}

override fun onResume() {
    onActivityStateChanged?.onResumed()
    super.onResume()
}
```

This method works for me

### Here is the java implementation for the above code, it may have compilation error because I just wrote it without any IDE

```
 interface OnActivityStateChanged{
    void onResumed()
    void onPaused()
}

....
public OnActivityStateChanged registerActivityState() {

  return new OnActivityStateChanged{
        @Override
        public void onResumed() {
            Log.d("SimpleTextListAdapter", "onResumed: ")
        }

        @Override
        public void onPaused() {

            Log.d("SimpleTextListAdapter", "onPaused: ")
        }

}

...

OnActivityStateChanged onActivityStateChanged = null
...

// after adapter intitialization, intialize your interface
onActivityStateChanged  = adapter.registerActivityState()


...

@Override
public fun onPause() {

    if(onActivityStateChanged != null)
        onActivityStateChanged.onPaused()
    super.onPause()
}

@Override
public fun onResume() {

    if(onActivityStateChanged != null)
        onActivityStateChanged.onResumed()
    super.onResume()
}
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any problem in implementation, also If your problem is resolved please, mark my answer as accepted

Comment: thanks for the answer @Aziz, i'm implementing it in my code, if it works, i'll surely mark it is accepted .

Comment: can you share java code for the registering part ?

Comment: still waiting for the reply. 
It would be great help if you can share java code , at least for the registering part. I don't understand kotlin.

Comment: Well thats why I asked about implementation lol, Because somewhere I thought you might be having trouble with kotlin. But sure, I will help you with the java code as well.

Comment: that's great, i'll be waiting

Comment: Check my updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198075/discussion-between-syed-hissaan-and-aziz).